# How to put a tooltip on this?

Tags: css

Here's a few lines from the start of my menu. That ought to be enough - it'sa  standard pure CSS drop-down menu

```
<!-- start of menu -->
<div class="menu" style="width:100%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="welcome.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="welcome.php">Input data</a>
      <ul>
      <li><form action="input.php"  method="post"><div><input type="hidden" name="db" value="a" class="menu_item_button"><button class="menu_item_button">a</button></div></form></li>
      <li><form action="input.php"  method="post"><div><input type="hidden" name="db" value="b" class="menu_item_button"><button class="menu_item_button">b</button></div></form></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

You will see that I am using a form for each link because I want to use POST throughout the entire site, with no GET.

Everything is working fine, but ... I can never resist an extra.

I have some more descriptive text for the menu items and I would like to display it as a tooltip if the user hovers the mouse over a menu item.

AFAIK, I can only do that with HREF - is that correct?

And when I try to do so, I can't get it to validate at W3C - HREF not allowed, even if I wrap it in DIV or Span.

So - is there any way that I can have a tooltip if the user hovers over those LIs?

---

Update: apologies - I forgot to mention that I am not allowed to use JS.

Comment: Just a note, if you're using POSTs for your menus, this effectively means that your site is not going to get crawled via your menu structure. You'd need a sitemap.

Comment: Also, you'll annoy users that try to use the back button.

Comment: +1 all round. It's an intranet site, so I don't need it to be crawled. I did consider using GET for things that the user might wish to bookmark, such as searches, but have had bad experiences with users who like to tweak things "just to see what happens". What happens is usually that they say "it's broke" and demand support. In this case I am a flight away, so they'll get POST and like it!! (grr)    Nick, could you expand on that "trouble with the back button"?

Comment: Try hitting the back button after POSTing in various browsers and you'll see what he means (hint: do you want to resubmit this form?) Also, could you elaborate on the "just to see what happens"? I can't be the only one that just doesn't get _at all_ why you'd want to use POST when you're obviously GETting something…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `title` attribute

```
title="Your tooltip"
```

Like this ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/faceleg/fLKAM/)):

```
<!-- start of menu -->
<div class="menu" style="width:100%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto">
    <ul>
        <li title="Your tooltip"><a href="welcome.php">Home</a></li>
        <li title="Another tooltip"><a href="welcome.php">Input data</a>
            <ul>
                <li title="Yet another tooltip"><form action="input.php"  method="post"><div><input type="hidden" name="db" value="a" class="menu_item_button"><button class="menu_item_button">a</button></div></form></li>
                <li title="And another tooltip">
                    <form action="input.php"  method="post">
                        <div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="db" value="b" class="menu_item_button">
                            <button class="menu_item_button">b</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

One may use it on all elements except:

> applet, base, basefont, head, html, meta, param, script, title

From [About.com's Attribute Documentation](http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/p/blattitle.htm)

Answer (score -2):

For accessibility I suggest you just convert all get vars to post vars by including the snippet below on top of your script. that is if you are using PHP. It converts all get vars to post vars..

```
// get vars to post vars */
if(isset($_GET)) {
   foreach ($_GET as $key => $val) {
   $_POST["$key"] = $val;
}}
```

This will make the site more accessible.
You links will look like this:

```
<li><a href="input.php?db=b">B</a></li>
```